# Comparing two lists, boundaries checks and typecasting

Tags: python

This is an automation code written in Python, code is initiated with robotscript. This function validates that my input list matches the list that the program provides me with. I need to do typecasting because robotframework only allows my to insert parameters as unicode strings, typecast is also needed so I can check values within range.

I want to know if this code can be better modified, I'm doing a lot of iteration through list and nested lists.
Any comments will be appreciated.

```
def validate_estimates(expect_coordinates):
    """ Validates all Estimates lines that are drawn on display.
        input_param: expect_coordinates, which is a list of lists for validation
        Values that are collected from the UI need to be typecasted to either time or float
            for range check validation.
        Function, throws error ir sublists for input and actual values do not match as well if
            values from expected lists are not within range.
    """
    scene = squishtest.waitForObject("{type='isds::MainView' unnamed='1' visible='1' windowTitle='EdgeView'}")
    expect_coordinates_list = ast.literal_eval(expect_coordinates)
    measurement_values_list = []
    first_iter_special_case = True
    for si in squishtest.object.children(scene):
        if squishtest.className(si) == 'QGraphicsItem':
            if si.type == 65536:
                for ssi in squishtest.object.children(si):
                    for sssi in squishtest.object.children(ssi):
                        measurement_values = []
                        try:
                            qoo = squishtest.castToQObject(ssi)
                        except Exception, e:
                            raise AssertionError("Error in typecast: ", e)

                        if first_iter_special_case:
                            for i in range(4):
                                if i == 0:
                                    measurement_values.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(qoo.measurementField), '%H:%M'))  # time value
                                elif i == 1 or i == 2:
                                    nm_str = str(qoo.measurementField)
                                    measurement_values.append(float(nm_str[:nm_str.find(' ')]))
                                elif i == 3:
                                    eet_str = str(qoo.measurementField)
                                    eet_str = eet_str[:eet_str.find(' ')]
                                    measurement_values.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(eet_str, '%H:%M'))  # time value
                                squishtest.mouseClick(squishtest.waitForObject(sssi))
                            first_iter_special_case = False
                        else:
                            for i in range(3):
                                if i == 0:
                                    measurement_values.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(qoo.measurementField), '%H:%M'))  # time value
                                elif i == 1:
                                    nm_str = str(qoo.measurementField)
                                    measurement_values.append(float(nm_str[:nm_str.find(' ')]))
                                elif i == 2:
                                    eet_str = str(qoo.measurementField)
                                    eet_str = eet_str[:eet_str.find(' ')]
                                    measurement_values.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(eet_str, '%H:%M'))  # time value
                                squishtest.mouseClick(squishtest.waitForObject(sssi))            
                    measurement_values_list.append(measurement_values) # append sublists to list

    # list lengths validations
    if len(measurement_values_list) != len(expect_coordinates_list):
        raise AssertionError('Error list lenghts: Validation list must be of length[%s] not length[%s]' % (len(measurement_values_list), len(expect_coordinates_list)))
    for i in range(len(measurement_values_list)):
        if len(measurement_values_list[i]) != len(expect_coordinates_list[i]):
            raise AssertionError('Error sublist lengths: validation sublist number[%s] is of length[%s] should be of length[%s]' % (i+1, len(expect_coordinates_list[i]), len(measurement_values_list[i])))

    # validation of values from isds and our expected values
    for i in range(len(measurement_values_list)):
        for j in range(len(measurement_values_list[i])):
            if type(measurement_values_list[i][j]) is datetime.datetime:
                utility_time_in_range(measurement_values_list[i][j], expect_coordinates_list[i][j])
            elif isinstance(measurement_values_list[i][j], float): 
                if not (measurement_values_list[i][j]-30 <= float(expect_coordinates_list[i][j]) <= measurement_values_list[i][j]+30):
                    raise AssertionError('Error given value[%s] outsite lower boundaries[%s] and uper boundaries[%s]' % (expect_coordinates_list[i][j], measurement_values_list[i][j]-30, measurement_values_list[i][j]+30))


def utility_time_in_range(actual_time, expected_time):
    """ Utility function
        input_param: actual_time and expected_time.
        Verifies that expected_time is within boundraries, otherwise throws out error.
    """
    et = datetime.datetime.strptime(expected_time, '%H:%M')
    lower_time_boundaries = actual_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    higher_time_boundaries = actual_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    if not (lower_time_boundaries <= et <= higher_time_boundaries):
        raise AssertionError('Error in time: Given value[%s] outsite lower boundaries[%s] or uper boundaries[%s]' % (expected_time, lower_time_boundaries, higher_time_boundaries))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is that the first function is way too long.  In general
either try to reduce the amount of work, or split it into smaller chunks
early.

Next, the nesting is also quite deep in the first loop.  IMO one of the
best ways to tackle that is to `continue` instead of nesting too many
`if`s.

- Use of magic constants.  What is `65536` supposed to mean?
- Variable names.  `si`/`ssi`/`sssi` doesn't ring a bell for me.  Might
  be okay for you; I'd still use something more descriptive.

`qoo` can be moved up one `for`-loop.

The `for i in range(...): if i == 0 ...` seems *really* weird.  If it's
just done to reuse the wait method, I'd rather create a helper function
for that and deal with the once duplicated step separately.  It's way
clearer if not done with this idiom.

- The `append`ing to `measurement_values_list` has the wrong
  indentation?  It should probably append the currently assembled list
  instead of only once at the end.
- Instead of using `for i in range(len(..))` it's generally better to
  use either normal iteration over the elements, `enumerate`, or
  something like `zip`/`izip`.

I can't tell if the `if-else` blocks with the type tests should have an
alternative clause for the "error" case; I'd maybe go with a normal
`else` and assert that the type is e.g. `float` if that was meant.

- Don't recompute values.  If in doubt assign it to a meaningful name
  and reuse.  E.g. the `x - 30`/`x + 30` parts, or lengths and so on.
- In general use `instanceof` instead of `type(...) is`.  Don't know if
  it was intended this way though.

All in all it would probably look like this (note that `x` to `w` should
be replaced with either better names or moved into smaller helper
functions; same for `some_step` and `wait_for_sssi`):

```
def gather_measurement_values_list():
    measurement_values_list = []
    first_iter_special_case = True

    for si in squishtest.object.children(scene):
        if squishtest.className(si) != 'QGraphicsItem':
            continue

        if si.type != 65536:
            continue

        for ssi in squishtest.object.children(si):
            try:
                qoo = squishtest.castToQObject(ssi)
            except Exception, e:
                raise AssertionError("Error in typecast: ", e)

            for sssi in squishtest.object.children(ssi):
                measurement_values = []

                def wait_for_sssi():
                    squishtest.mouseClick(squishtest.waitForObject(sssi))

                measurement_values.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(str(qoo.measurementField), '%H:%M'))  # time value
                wait_for_sssi()

                def some_step():
                    nm_str = str(qoo.measurementField)
                    measurement_values.append(float(nm_str[:nm_str.find(' ')]))
                    wait_for_sssi()

                some_step()

                # repeat previous step once more
                if first_iter_special_case:
                    first_iter_special_case = False
                    some_step()

                eet_str = str(qoo.measurementField)
                eet_str = eet_str[:eet_str.find(' ')]
                measurement_values.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(eet_str, '%H:%M'))  # time value
                wait_for_sssi()

                measurement_values_list.append(measurement_values) # append sublists to list

    return measurement_values_list


def validate_estimates(expect_coordinates):
    """ Validates all Estimates lines that are drawn on display.
        input_param: expect_coordinates, which is a list of lists for validation
        Values that are collected from the UI need to be typecasted to either time or float
            for range check validation.
        Function, throws error ir sublists for input and actual values do not match as well if
            values from expected lists are not within range.
    """
    scene = squishtest.waitForObject("{type='isds::MainView' unnamed='1' visible='1' windowTitle='EdgeView'}")
    expect_coordinates_list = ast.literal_eval(expect_coordinates)
    measurement_values_list = gather_measurement_values_list()

    # list lengths validations
    if len(measurement_values_list) != len(expect_coordinates_list):
        raise AssertionError('Error list lengths: Validation list must be of length[%s] not length[%s]' % (len(measurement_values_list), len(expect_coordinates_list)))

    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(measurement_values_list, expect_coordinates_list)):
        if len(x) != len(y):
            raise AssertionError('Error sublist lengths: validation sublist number[%s] is of length[%s] should be of length[%s]' % (i+1, len(x), len(y)))

    # validation of values from isds and our expected values
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(measurement_values_list, expect_coordinates_list)):
        for j, (v, w) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
            if type(v) is datetime.datetime:
                utility_time_in_range(v, w)
            elif isinstance(v, float):
                if not (v - 30 <= float(w) <= v + 30):
                    raise AssertionError('Error given value[%s] outsite lower boundaries[%s] and uper boundaries[%s]' % (w, v - 30, v + 30))


def utility_time_in_range(actual_time, expected_time):
    """ Utility function
        input_param: actual_time and expected_time.
        Verifies that expected_time is within boundraries, otherwise throws out error.
    """
    et = datetime.datetime.strptime(expected_time, '%H:%M')
    lower_time_boundaries = actual_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    higher_time_boundaries = actual_time + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
    if not (lower_time_boundaries <= et <= higher_time_boundaries):
        raise AssertionError('Error in time: Given value[%s] outsite lower boundaries[%s] or uper boundaries[%s]' % (expected_time, lower_time_boundaries, higher_time_boundaries))
```